# J2ME - BlackBerry - design patterns

Tags: blackberry, java-me, design-patterns

There are several publications about patterns in j2me:
[Architectural manifesto: The MVC design pattern in MIDP development by Mikko Kontio](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wireless/library/wi-arch6/)
[Identification of Design Patterns for Mobile Services with J2ME by J. Narsoo and N. Mohamudally](http://proceedings.informingscience.org/InSITE2008/IISITv5p623-643Narsoo507.pdf)
[Big designs for small devices by By Ben Hui](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2002/jw-1213-j2medesign.html)

Patterns I use sometimes:
**MVC** - to separate UI from controller classes and data structures, may be useful for code reuse on different platforms
**Command** - to reuse code in user interaction and app work-flow
**Interface** - to simplify several components use (ex different types of connections or data storage) and component testing (see [Blackberry - change latitude and longitude on the device to test app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920303/blackberry-change-latitude-and-longitude-on-the-device-to-test-app/943305#943305))

Also **Observer** may be used for UI update tasks(see [sample with HttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138100/need-help-with-java-design-of-http-requester))

What are your favorite patterns in J2ME/BlackBerry?

Answer (score 1):

How about using Singleton to handle settings/configurations.. and factory pattern to cover about UI theme (for example). I'm also still new in developing blackberry, I find it quite difficult to know which pattern is suitable for one conditions or another.